# Xammp only My sql not starting this error msg showing

Tags: mysql, xampp, localserver

I Get This Error Message Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

Answer (score 0):

Rename the folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old (you can use any name)
Create a new folder mysql/data Copy the content that resides in mysql/backup to the new mysql/data folder
Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to mysql/data (skipping the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old)
Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace it inside the mysql/data folder
Start MySQL from the XAMPP control panel

Comment: it works great... i first copied this file - xammp/mysql/data/ibdata1 than paste it to new data folder that i created and my database is back so this file is very important don't delete this file never ever if you want your database back.

Answer (score 0):

shutting down MySQL can cause corruption which means you have to repair or delete your tables. This can easily be avoided by running XAMPP as administrator.